# How to pass test filed value from one view to other?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an application were i have two pages :

page1

in which i have 1 textfield and one submit button.

when user enter the value in a text field,the value entered in a textfiled should get display on next page.

page2 have
 1 textfield to display the value ,entered in a first page and an edit button,to edit the text if he want's

if he click on edit button he should move to page one,were he can see the value he has entered and should change

I am able to pass textfield value from one page to other but not able to display the same value  on page one when user click the edit button..

following is my page1 .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "new.h"

@interface tryViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

-(IBAction)submit;

@end
```

following is my page1 .m file:

```
#import "tryViewController.h"

@implementation tryViewController

@synthesize textField;



- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.

    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];

}


-(IBAction)submit

{

    new *pg = [new alloc];
    pg.str = textField.text;
    [self .view addSubview:pg.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:pg animated:YES];
}

@end
```

following is my page2 .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "tryViewController.h"

@interface new : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;

    NSString *str;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str;

-(IBAction)back;


@end


following is my page2 .m file:


#import "new.h"


@implementation new
@synthesize str;


- (void)viewDidLoad {


    txtField.text = str;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}





- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)back
{
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ... strange.
Try to use class name beginning with a capital letter with an human readable name.

Why do you use modal view controller instead of navigation controller?

Try this kind of code:

EditViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ShowViewController.h"

@interface EditViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

-(IBAction)submit;
@end
```

EditViewController.m

```
#import "EditViewController.h"

@implementation EditViewController

@synthesize textField;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.textField = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)submit {
    ShowViewController *showViewController = [[ShowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowViewController" bundle:nil];
    showViewController.string = textField.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

ShowViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface new : ShowViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *string;

-(IBAction)back;

@end
```

ShowViewController.m

```
#import "ShowViewController.h"

@implementation ShowViewController
    @synthesize string;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    txtField.text = string;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

In your MainWindow.xib add a Navigation Controller (or create your project with the navigation controller wizard.

If you doesn't want a nab bar just add a

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

in your application delegate.